# Website layout changed in latest firefox version

Tags: html, css, firefox, layout

I have a website that's been up and running for a few years now with no problems. Then I upgraded to the latest version of Firefox (89.0.1) and suddenly any 'div's are too small for the content, but only within forms, so that fields and text appear on the following lines and/or overlap, with the result that the forms look a total mess.
Safari, Vivaldi, Chrome etc. all work fine.
Anyone else have this issue? How can I make my layout browser-proof?

Here's the html (generated from a php program):

```css
    #headerLoginPanel
    {
        background-color: white;
        width: 1000px;
        height: 40px;
        padding-top: 20px;
        float: left;
        text-align: left;
        color: #0056b3;
    }

.loginLegend
    {
        width: 220px;
        height: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        padding-right: 10px;
        float: left;
    }
    
#loginUsername
    {
        width: 180px;
        height: 30px;
        float: left;
    }

#loginPassword
    {
        width: 240px;
        height: 30px;
        float: left;
    }

#loginSubmit
    {
        width: 80px;
        height: 30px;
        float: left;
    }

#forgotPassword
    {
        width: 210px;
        height: 30px;
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 15px;
        float: left;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="headerLoginPanel">
            <form method="post" action="verify_login.php">
                <div class="loginLegend"></div>
                <div id="loginUsername">
          Username: <input type="text" name="username" size="10" value="" />
        </div>
                <div id="loginPassword">
          Password: <input type="password" name="password" size="16" value="" />
        </div>
                <div id="loginSubmit">
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="log in" />
        </div>
                <div id="forgotPassword">
          <a href="index.php?page=7" target="_self">Forgot your username<br />
          or password?</a>
        </div>
            </form>
    </div>
```

[Here's what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjnd0.png)

[Here's what it looks like in Firefox since a few days ago[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZDAg.png)

(There are many forms on the website, this is just the simplest one. It serves to illustrate the problem.)

Comment: Can you put some code into your question so we can see the problem for ourselves.

Comment: @A Haworth: Code duly added. This is just one example, but there are many, most of them being quite complex. The example above isn't such a problem, just looks a bit untidy, but in other places the effect is pretty bad. As I say it's only in Firefox that this happens.